# "HasPrecision" issue in EntityFramework (version=6.1.3)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

I am not able to use "**HasPrecision**" in *EntityFramework (version=6.1.3)*.

It Showing me error -

> 'PrimitivePropertyConfiguration' does not contain a definition for
>   'HasPrecision' and no extension method 'HasPrecision' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'PrimitivePropertyConfiguration' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there anything I am missing ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: are your latitude and longitude properties both decimals?

Comment: @HardikVinzava As in type `decimal`? Can you show the definition?

Comment: @HardikVinzava Are you doing this in the `OnModelCreating` override method? What happens if you use `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder`? Can you show more of your code in the question?

Comment: That's odd. It should be looking for DecimalPropertyConfiguration if it is indeed of decimal type. Something we're missing it seems.

Comment: @user1666620 added full class file snapshot.

Comment: @HardikVinzava can you show where `latitude` and `longitude` are declared?

Comment: When you do post more code, could you post the text using the markdown conventions, rather than screen shots?  That was helpful for the error message, but with the code we'll want to cut-n-paste to attempt a reproduction.

Comment: @user1666620 thanks for guiding me in the right direction. Actually, for try and catch I made both the fields double and that's why HasPrecision is not coming. after changing them to decimal it's working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HasPrecision(byte,byte)` is only available on `DecimalPropertyConfiguration` in this scenario.  (`HasPrecision(byte)` is defined on `DateTimePropertyConfiguration`.)

The property that is being mapped must be `decimal` for `EntityMappingConfiguration.Property<>(...)` to return the correct fluent configuration class in the chain.  That it is returning `PrimitivePropertyConfiguration` implies that the declared types are something besides `decimal`, `DateTime`,`String`, or `Byte[]`.  Each of these has a more specific property configuration class.

Comment: Thanks Marc. i was facing the same issue with IsFixedLength(). Resolved.